# Как из метода вернуть Observable<boolean> не содержащий ошибок?

Tags: typescript, angular5

Вот из такого метода:

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | boolean {

return this.accountService.update().pipe(map(data => {
  if (this.accountService.role == Role.admin) {
    return true;
  } else {
    this.router.navigateByUrl("");
    return false;
  }
}),
  //вот заместо этой ошибки нужно просто вернуть false
  catchError(err => {
    return throwError(err);
  }));
```

}

Нужно вернуть просто вернуть Observable не содержащей ошибок, за место ошибки вернуть false. Подскажите пожалуйста как это сделать. Спасибо.

Comment: `catchError(() => of(false))`

Answer (score -1):

```
private varBool: BehaviorSubject<boolean>;

constructor() {
    this.varBool= new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
}

public getBoolean(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.varBool.asObservable();
}
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Еще бы знать как оно работает, кто такой ужасный апи придумал...

Comment: этот ответ не несет в себе смысловой нагрузки и в принципе не имеет отношения к тому, как использовать оператор `catchError`

Comment: Да что тут, все понятно, заместо:

Comment: @overthesanity в вопросе четко выделен фрагмент, который нужно заменить (я не оперирую всеми условиями, при которых автор задал вопрос) поэтому я ему показал как именно можно сделать то, что он хочет. Вы же не выполнили условий автора вопроса. Так в чем же моя ошибка?

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц, в коде есть комментарий `вот заместо этой ошибки нужно просто вернуть false`, где связь между оператором `catchError` и `this.varBool= new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);` ??

Comment: @overthesanity но как раз catchError и нужно заменить

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц, зачем?

Comment: @overthesanity затем, что в вопросе так написано

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц, вы понимаете вообще как работает оператор `catchError` и как отлавливать ошибки в потоках? зачем вообще создавать генератор с кешированием и возвращать поток? почему тогда просто не написать `return false`? почему тогда просто не вернуть сам генератор? почему тогда просто не вернуть закешированное значение через `getValue()`? Зачем пытаться отвечать на вопрос о rxjs если вы о rxjs не имеете ни малейшего представления?